# Sort Excel Pivot Table By Month

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am trying to sort data in a pivot table. I am hoping to end up with a table that has row labels with my data types, and then 12 monthly columns with a count of each type in each column. So far I have 12 columns that have a full year total in each column. I now need to filter that down by month. I have a field that has date and time in it, so I would want to filter on that field. I don't see a date option to filter by - rather I have a value filter option. I can only filter on the count of the incident type, rather than on the dates. If I try to manually filter I will be checking hundreds of boxes to get the count for each date in the month. How do I filter this by date?

Comment: Filter it out of the raw data before the pivot see's it.  I believe if you filter the data then refresh the pivot the date will fall off or be just that date...

Comment: It's really hard to understand the case - could you please provide a sample? Screen is fine.

Comment: Likely you'll need to create an extra "month" column in your source data - you can then filter/group on that.

Comment: I would love to add some screenshots here to help clarify my question but can't seem to find how to add them.

Answer (score 1):

Add a formula that marks the record for exclusion on column F and then use that as the filter in the pivot table.

[image: Excel Screenshot]